# UITabBar Showing More Icons Instead of "More" Option

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm currently attempting to use the `UITabBar` for an iOS app that contains 7 `tabBar` Items.

When I use the storyboard, I am able to achieve all 7 `tabBarItems`.
When I programmatically add the `tabBarItems`, It forces a "More" Button to access the other tabBarItems.

Is there a way programmatically keep all the 7 tabBarItems as when I am manually create the `UITabBar`?

[image: Example of What I'm talking about]

The Code that I'm using to build the uitabbar in my appdelegate.m

```
  self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
  SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
  ThirdViewController *thirdVC = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];
  FourthViewController *fourthVC = [[FourthViewController alloc] init];
  FifthViewController *fifthVC = [[FifthViewController alloc] init];
  SixthViewController *sixthVC = [[SixthViewController alloc] init];
  SeventhViewController *seventhVC = [[SeventhViewController alloc] init];

  NSArray *controllers = @[firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC, fourthVC, fifthVC, sixthVC, seventhVC];

  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
  [_window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Answer (score 5):

By design you are limited to 5, from apple docs

> If you add more than five items to the viewControllers property, the
>   tab bar controller automatically inserts a special view controller
>   (called the More view controller) to handle the display of the
>   additional items. The More view controller provides a custom interface
>   that lists the additional view controllers in a table, which can
>   expand to accommodate any number of view controllers. The More view
>   controller cannot be customized or selected and does not appear in any
>   of the view controller lists managed by the tab bar controller. It
>   appears automatically when it is needed and is separate from your
>   custom content. You can get a reference to it though by accessing the
>   moreNavigationController property of UITabBarController.

It just not recommended , but if you insist you will need to use a library or perhaps use a tool bar and add many UIBarButtonItems to it.

Comment: thanks, i just wanted to see some additional thoughts on this out there. i kind of like this library: [link](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar)

Comment: @ArmYourselves nice, this one is really great