# How to display more than 4 tabs in a single row without having "More" option iOS

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my **`Xamarin.Forms`** project, in iOS I have 7 tabs in a page, only 4 tabs are displaying in single row than I have "More" menu. In Android all tabs displaying in single row and looking good.

[image]

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="edTheSIS.Views.StaffTimeTablePage"
             SelectedTabIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}"
             xmlns:customViews="clr-namespace:edTheSIS.CustomViews;assembly=edTheSIS">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <customViews:TitleView prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="true"></customViews:TitleView>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage Title="MON">
        <StackLayout>
            <customViews:DumyView BackgroundColor="#f26422"></customViews:DumyView>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView x:Name="list1" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeTablesList}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <customViews:TimeTableView prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="true"></customViews:TimeTableView>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>

     <ContentPage Title="TUE">
     ......
     ......
```

I just want to avoid "More" option and need all tabs visible how can I do that?

Comment: Then how you show 7 tabs in that small width ?

Comment: If you see above screenshot there is enough space available to have rest of tabs like Android.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23354046/4984832

Comment: Best option is to build custom view which will work as tabbar or use any library